# How do I change variables depending which anchor link opens the side?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have a Nuxt 3 project and on my page I have 5 different divs for the same spot, which one is shown is set by variables, if they are true the connected content is shown, I used v-if for that.

Now I have to put some anchor links to that Page one for each of those texts and depending which one is opened the page should jump to that space /link anchor links do) and show the correlating div. But how do I change the variable depending on the opened anchor link?

The data Object with my variables:

```
        data() {
            return {
                mediaObj: {
                    Classic: true,
                    CellSpecific: false,
                    SerumFree: false,
                    Cryopreservation: false,
                    Insect: false,
                    readMore: false
                },

            }
        },
```

the default one that's true is Classic but when he opens the page with the #CellSpecific anchor it should set the CellSpecific anchor to true instead.

The functions I currently use to change those variables are:

```
            changeMenuMedia(n) {
                this.falseMenuMedia();
                this.mediaObj[String(n)] = true
            },

            falseMenuMedia(){
                this.mediaObj = {
                        Classic: false,
                        CellSpecific: false,
                        SerumFree: false,
                        Cryopreservation: false,
                        Insect: false,
                    }
            },
```

But they are always called by a button press on the page itself. I need it depending on the anchor in the link. Is that possible, if so how?